# Static classes becomes abstract sealed in IL code but we can not create abstract sealed class in our C# code

Tags: c#, .net

I've had a confusion while working with the static classes in C#.

I've created a static class in C# and when I checked the IL code it becomes abstract sealed class.

```
//C# Code below 
internal static class Converter

//IL Code Below
.class private auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit StaticExample.Converter
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
```

But when I try to create a class in C# with abstract and sealed keywork it's not allowing to do so.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From this [PDF on Microsoft.com](https://download.microsoft.com/download/d/c/1/dc1b219f-3b11-4a05-9da3-2d0f98b20917/partition%20ii%20metadata.doc), there are described CIL tokens (quote below; from section 10.1.4). What you should understand is, that the Common Intermediate Language (CIL) doesn't represent 1 to 1 mapping to C# code with same naming - in this case the word `abstract` has a little different meaning in each of those languages. CIL Tokens:

> Attributes that specify special semantics are `abstract` and `sealed`. These attributes can be used together.
>
> > `abstract` specifies that this type shall not be instantiated. If a type contains abstract methods, that type
> > shall be declared as an abstract type.
> > `sealed` specifies that a type shall not have derived classes. All value types shall be sealed.

> > [Rationale: Virtual methods of sealed types are effectively instance methods, since they cannot be overridden.
> > Framework authors should use sealed classes sparingly since they do not provide a convenient building block
> > for user extensibility. Sealed classes can be necessary when the implementation of a set of virtual methods for
> > a single class (typically multiple interfaces) becomes interdependent or depends critically on implementation
> > details not visible to potential derived classes.
> > A type that is both `abstract` and `sealed` should have only static members, and serves as what some
> > languages call a ―`namespace`‖ or ―`static class`‖. end rationale]